# "switchEditors is not defined" with wp_editor() in jQuery UI tabs

Tags: plugins, jquery, tinymce, jquery-ui, tabs

Making a WordPress plugin, using WordPress 3.5.2

I'm using wp_editor() on the front end, inside jquery UI tabs [ajax loading tabs + 2 editors on the same panel], and I'm getting the following error, when clicking visual.

```
switchEditors is not defined
```

I've even tried adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582764/tinymce-with-ajax-tabs); it errors out tinyMCE is not defined.

this is my code:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="wpsca_ul">
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ).'/?wpsca=wpscalist';?>" title="manage list"><?php echo __('Manage Pages','wpsca_lang');?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ).'/?wpsca=wpscaaddedit';?>" title="manage addedit"><?php echo __('Add Page','wpsca_lang');?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ).'/?wpsca=wpscasettings';?>" title="manage settings"><?php echo __('Settings','wpsca_lang');?></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="manage_list">loading...</div>
<div id="manage_addedit" class="ui-tabs-hide">loading...</div>
<div id="manage_settings" class="ui-tabs-hide">loading...</div>
</div><!-- tabs -->
```

And I'm picking the tabs up on init;

Any direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have tackled this by putting TinyMCE on the first tab, and making it a static tab, all others are still ajax, would still like it to be ajax, if anyone has any solutions.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="wpsca_ul">
    <li><a href="#wpsca_addedit" title="add page"><?php echo __('Add Page','wpsca_lang');?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ).'/?wpsca=wpscalist';?>" title="manage addedit"><?php echo __('Manage Pages','wpsca_lang');?></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ).'/?wpsca=wpscasettings';?>" title="manage settings"><?php echo __('Settings','wpsca_lang');?></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="wpsca_addedit">
< ? php wp_editor() coding ?>
</div>
<div id="manage_list" class="ui-tabs-hide">loading...</div>
<div id="manage_settings" class="ui-tabs-hide">loading...</div>
</div><!-- tabs -->
```

Comment: It is unlikely to work as ajax since tinymce requires JS to be loaded for it to work, and this loading of the JS is hard to be done in ajax